# Magento admin skin loading from base/default instead of default/default

Tags: administration

I am migrating my server from the dev to live, on the live server when I go to the admin section I am getting 404s for the css.

For example instead of trying to load the css from

/skin/adminhtml/default/default/reset.css

it is trying to load from here:

/skin/adminhtml/base/default/reset.css

What could cause this?

Comment: put reset.css to  /skin/adminhtml/default/default/

Comment: where you have specified your css?

Answer (score 5):

The backend has the same fallback mechanism as the frontend regarding the themes.
The last fallback level is always `base/default` for both of them.

The reason you reach that level for admin is: you don't have the file you requested in `default/default` OR the file is not readable.

I would put my money on "door number 2". Check the permissions on your files and folders.

Answer (score 1):

To change the path for the admin skin, I think you want this in your config:

```
<config>
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <design>
                <theme>
                    <default>yourdesignthemename</default>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
    </stores>
</config>
```

That will allow you to use the path default/yourdesignthemename and will fall back to default/default if files are missing (CE 1.8.1)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to get `/skin/adminhtml/default/default/` path then you can use
**Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl();** or **Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl('reset.css');**

Then you can get `skin/adminhtml/default/default/reset.css`
You can try to test it on your controllers